# Is Umbraco CMS is free or paid?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-blog

Umbraco CMS is free or paid? Please give me information i want to start work on  project for my organization using Umbraco CMS

Comment: Check the license [in the repo](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS). I'ts [MIT](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/dev-v7/LICENSE.md) which means you can do anything you want with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umbraco is open source CMS so you can install it and host it yourself for free.

They have a cloud if you want to host the site on their servers and that is not free - more about it [here](https://umbraco.com/pricing/)

Answer (score 2):

Umbraco is free open source however there are some packages/addons such as Umbraco Forms/Contour which you need to pay for, when using it in production. Forms allows you to manage HTTP form submissions within the CMS and configure what to do next such as send an email on submission etc.

Like Davor mentioned they have a cloud service which will handle upgrades and it include forms too. https://umbraco.com/pricing/

What's also a good thing to checkout is the https://our.umbraco.org/ site which has useful information on packages created by the community and tutorials.